# How to start stored procedure from Access then continue VBA code execution

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I run my SQL procedures from Access using this method:

```
Screen.MousePointer = 11
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=10.0.0.1"
    cn.Open
        cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ProcName"
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Param1", adInteger, adParamInput, , cboParam1ComboBox.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnMsg", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 500)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        cmd.Execute
        MsgBox cmd.Parameters("@ReturnMsg").Value
    cn.Close
Screen.MousePointer = 0
```

But how can I start a procedure and then leave it to run in the background? The reason is that sometimes the proc might take a long time to run. And the procs I want to run email the user when complete thus I want the user to start the proc via the Access GUI, then close the GUI and just wait for the email.

Answer (score -1):

Use [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169(v=sql.110).aspx) to start an Agent job that runs your stored procedure.

See [Job.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms202348.aspx)

Comment: I did think that, but what about parameters?

Comment: one solution would be to have TSQL as part of the job read them from a table.